# Creating an anonymous object who must have the dot in Key name and put it inside another anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

I'm making a `JSON body` for an `elasticsearch` query.

I have this `dynamic`:

```
var hlBodyText = new
{
  bodyText = new { }
};
```

But there's a case in which the name must be `bodyText.exact = new { }`, but obviously I'm not allowed to do it and return the error message:

`Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

There's a way to make that value name with the `dot char`?

#### EDIT

Furthermore, I have to put this object inside another object, like this:

```
var fieldsInner = new
{
  hlBodyText.bodyText
};
```

What could be the best way to get this result but with the property name set with the dot?

#### EDIT #2

I created a `class` with all my parameters beacause I thought the `JsonProperty attribute` could help me.

```
internal class ElasticSearchHighlightsModel
{
  [JsonProperty("bodyText")]
  public object bodyText { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("title")]
  public object title { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("shortDescription")]
  public object shortDescription { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("bodyText.exact")]
  public object bodyTextExact { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("title.exact")]
  public object titleExact { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("shortDescription.exact")]
  public object shortDescriptionExact { get; set; }
}
```

then in my method i have a condition for which I have to use some params or others.

```
// ...some code...
else
{
  var hlBodyText = new ElasticSearchHighlightsModel() { bodyTextExact = new { } };
  var hlTitle = new ElasticSearchHighlightsModel() { titleExact = new { } };
  var hlShortDescription = new ElasticSearchHighlightsModel() { shortDescriptionExact = new { } };

  var fieldsInner = new
  {
    hlBodyText.bodyTextExact,
    hlTitle.titleExact,
    hlShortDescription.shortDescriptionExact,
  };

  var fieldsContainer = new
  {
    pre_tags = preTags,
    post_tags = postTags,
    fields = fieldsInner,
  };
  return fieldsContainer;
}
```

But the `fieldsInner` object have the parameter names (bodyTextExact, titleExact etc...), not the `JsonProperty attribute` ones.

Comment: How do you convert this to Json?

Comment: I don't convert it, this is a little part of a big object I send to `ES` using `Flurl`

Comment: `dynamic` is not a type. Is this a local variable or a class property? If it's a property you can use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

Comment: @DStanley is a local variable. Maybe create a class with properties could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** using `Dictionary`, then passed it inside an `anonymous type obj`:

```
IDictionary highlitsFieldsContainer = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// ... some code
highlitsFieldsContainer["bodyText.exact"] = new { };
highlitsFieldsContainer["title.exact"] = new { };
var fieldsContainer = new
{
  fields = highlitsFieldsContainer,
};

// OUTPUT: fieldsContainer = { fields = { bodyText.exact = {}, title.exact = {} } }
```

And used a `RouteValueDictionary class` to read that values when `elasticsearch` send his response.

```
RouteValueDictionary _res = new RouteValueDictionary(dynamicResponse.highlights);
if (_res["shortDescription.exact"] != null)
{ 
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems this you are looking for,later u convert dictionary to json

```
Dictionary<string,object> obj=new Dictionary<string,object>();

obj["bodyText.exact"]=new object{};
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but maybe that's not enough for my case.
I added some informations on question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating an anonymous type (not "dynamic") and wanting to serialize it with a different name that is not valid in C#.  To do that you'll need to use a named type and use the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)
 attribute:

```
internal class HlBodyText 
{
    [JsonProperty("bodyText.exact")]
    public DateTime bodyText { get; set; }
}
```

and create an instance of it:

```
var hlBodyText = new HlBodyText() 
{
  bodyText = new { }
};
```

Comment: Not working yet. `fieldsInner` object have not the `JsonParams attribute` value but directly the `class parameter` name.